# Curious about this JavaScript Map function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm studying this JS function:

```
function solution (array, commands) {
     return commands.map (v => {
         return array.slice(v[0] -1, v[1]).sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(v[2] -1, v[2])[0];
     });
}
```

I do not know what `v[0] -1` does.

If `commands` is a two-dimensional array like this:

```
[[2,5,4] [4,4,1] [1,7,3]]
```

What does `v[0]` mean and what does it mean to do `-1` to it like `v[0] -1`?

Comment: `map` iterates through each item in `commands`. The current iteration/item is `v`. Therefore, `v[0]` would refer to the first item in one of child arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is simply accessing the indexes of each array within `commands`

```js
[[2,5,4], [4,4,1], [1,7,3]].forEach(arrayV => console.log(arrayV));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

`v[0]` is simply getting the first index of each array

```js
[[2,5,4], [4,4,1], [1,7,3]].forEach(arrayV => console.log(arrayV[0]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

And, `v[0] - 1` is only subtracting `1` to first value on array `v`

```js
[[2,5,4], [4,4,1], [1,7,3]].forEach(arrayV => console.log(arrayV[0] - 1));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The function `Array.prototype.map()` loops over the array and pass each element to the handler.  In your case, is passing arrays from each index.

Answer (score 2):

What it means is this:

```
v[0]
```

This gets the first element from the array called `v`.

```
-1
```

This takes 1 away from the first element in the array `v`.

Answer (score 2):

If `commands` is `[[2,5,4],[4,4,1],[1,7,3]]`

then in the context of `commands.map( v => {})`, `v[0]` is not an array; it's one of the numbers. `map()` will take each sub array and assign it to `v`, so when you access `v[0]` you are getting the first element of the subarray:

```js
let commands=[[2,5,4],[4,4,1],[1,7,3]]
let m  = commands.map(v => {
    console.log("v[0]:", v[0])
    // we don't know what array is so not sure what to return
    //return array.slice(v[0] -1, v[1]).sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(v[2] -1, v[2])[0];
    return "some value"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Jack's answer, I believe that the OP's confusion arises from overlooking the influence of the `map` function, viz:

- The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

So, the function in question will be called three times:  first with `[2,5,4],` then `[4,4,1]` and so on.  And so, *realizing this,* the code snippet as-written now makes sense:  `v[0]-1` is equal to `1` the first time, and so on.

- Now, having said all that – "I *hate* to encounter code like this," although of course I encounter it a lot as we all do.  Not only because it is fragile, but also because it makes me feel like I've stumbled upon an episode of *Name That Tune* where the original-programmer is trying to minimize keystrokes for no particular reason.  I dislike having to "puzzle out" how a piece of source-code works.